# jira REST API create issue including component

Tags: api, components, jira, jira-rest-api, bad-request

I am trying to create issue using Jira REST API incuding component. I am posting this JSON but I get The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Issue is:-Without component there is no error, but when component is there issue created. Any help? JSON:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": "keyGoesHere"
    },
    "assignee": {
      "name": "name.surname"
    },
    "component": {
      "name": "someName"
    },
    "summary": "test2",
    "description": "test2",
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Task"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer. Just in case someone needs it.

```
"components": [{
  "name": "someName"
}],
```

Comment: You are a godsend!